# Scaling a touchpad for use with Box2d in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to scale things by a PPM value just like the tutorial I am watching said but then I realized that I have a touchpad and the tutorial dosen't so I don't know what to do to scale it along with everything else. Everything I have tried dosen't work.

Here is my playscreen file: As you can see I have the touchpad in there but not scaled and everything else is scaled and works fine. *Note: My PPM value is float of 100*

```
package com.cyan.rdm.Screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Touchpad;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.Drawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
import com.cyan.rdm.Sprites.Char;
import com.cyan.rdm.rdmGame;

public class PlayScreen implements Screen{

    private rdmGame game;
    private Stage stage;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private Viewport stretchport;
    private Char character;
    private Label speedLabel;
    private boolean speedLabelVisibility = false;
    private boolean touchPadVisibility = true;

    // Map Loader
    private TmxMapLoader mploader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

    // Box 2D
    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;

    // TouchPad

    public Touchpad touchpad;
    public Touchpad.TouchpadStyle touchpadStyle;
    public Skin touchpadSkin;
    public Drawable touchBackground;
    public Drawable touchKnob;

    public PlayScreen(rdmGame game) {

        this.game = game;

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        stretchport = new StretchViewport(rdmGame.V_WIDTH / rdmGame.PPM, rdmGame.V_HEIGHT / rdmGame.PPM, cam);

        stage = new Stage(stretchport, game.batch);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        Label.LabelStyle font = new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE);

        Table table = new Table();
        table.setPosition(15 / rdmGame.PPM, 185 / rdmGame.PPM);

        speedLabel = new Label(String.format("%03d", character.SPEED), font);
        table.add(speedLabel).expandX();

        // Map
        mploader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = mploader.load("temp_tileset2.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / rdmGame.PPM);
        cam.position.set(stretchport.getWorldWidth() / 2,stretchport.getWorldHeight() /2, 0);

        // Box 2D

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);
        b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        character = new Char(world);

        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        PolygonShape hitbox = new PolygonShape();
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        Body body;

        // Normal Wall Collision
        for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(2).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) {
            Rectangle rectangle = ((RectangleMapObject) object).getRectangle();

            bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
            bodyDef.position.set((rectangle.getX() + rectangle.getWidth() /2) / rdmGame.PPM ,(rectangle.getY() + rectangle.getHeight() / 2) / rdmGame.PPM);

            body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

            hitbox.setAsBox(rectangle.getWidth() / 2 / rdmGame.PPM, rectangle.getHeight() / 2 / rdmGame.PPM);
            fixtureDef.shape = hitbox;
            body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        }

        // Red Wall Collision
        for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(3).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) {
            Rectangle rectangle = ((RectangleMapObject) object).getRectangle();

            bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
            bodyDef.position.set((rectangle.getX() + rectangle.getWidth() / 2) / rdmGame.PPM, (rectangle.getY() + rectangle.getHeight() / 2)  / rdmGame.PPM);

            body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

            hitbox.setAsBox(rectangle.getWidth() / 2 / rdmGame.PPM, rectangle.getHeight() / 2 / rdmGame.PPM);
            fixtureDef.shape = hitbox;
            body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        }



        //TouchPad

        touchpadSkin = new Skin();
        touchpadSkin.add("touchBackground", new Texture("touchBackground2.png"));
        touchpadSkin.add("touchKnob", new Texture("touch_circle2.png"));
        touchpadStyle = new Touchpad.TouchpadStyle();
        touchBackground = touchpadSkin.getDrawable("touchBackground");
        touchKnob = touchpadSkin.getDrawable("touchKnob");
        touchpadStyle.background = touchBackground;
        touchpadStyle.knob = touchKnob;

        touchpad = new Touchpad(10, touchpadStyle);
        touchpad.setBounds(8, 8, 64, 64);
        touchpad.scaleBy(1 / rdmGame.PPM,1 / rdmGame.PPM);

        stage.addActor(table);
        stage.addActor(touchpad);

        touchpad.setVisible(touchPadVisibility);



    }
    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    public void update(float dt) {

       // System.out.println("Char: " + character.b2Body.getPosition());
       // System.out.println("Touch: " + touchpad.);

        speedLabel.setText(String.format("%03d", character.SPEED));
        speedLabel.setVisible(speedLabelVisibility);

        handeInput(dt);
        world.step(1/60f, 6, 6);
        cam.update();
        renderer.setView(cam);


    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        update(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255 ,165, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.draw();
        renderer.render();
        b2dr.render(world, cam.combined);

        //Batch
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        game.batch.begin();



        game.batch.end();
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();


    }

    public void handeInput(float dt){

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.ESCAPE)){
            game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
        }

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP)){

        }

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN))

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.F3)){

            speedLabelVisibility = !speedLabelVisibility;
        }

        if(touchpad.getKnobPercentX() == 0 && touchpad.getKnobPercentY() == 0) {
            character.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0, 0));
        } else {
            character.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(character.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x + touchpad.getKnobPercentX()*character.SPEED, character.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y + touchpad.getKnobPercentY()*character.SPEED));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

        stretchport.update(width, height);

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use ppm on your touchpad. Ppm is just pixels per meter in the physics world. Ppm has nothing to do with Gui. You still use screen coordinates and size for Gui. So use a main stage for your game items with a camera that is px/ppm size and a viewport, and then  use another stage for Gui.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use two different viewports. One for your main stage divided by PPM and one for UI with normal resolution.